# NodeJS Typescrip.: Getting error: Must use import to load ES Module on sls offline command

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, serverless-framework

I have created a NodeJS / Typescript / Serverless framework-based solution to create AWS Lambdas and use serverless-offline lib/plugin to debug it locally in the VS Code. My github repo is [here](https://github.com/hasanfar/serveless-node-ts)

When executing the command

```
sls offline -s dev
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /Users/hasan/apps/zaghop/v2/API/node_modules/serverless-offline/src/index.js
  require() of ES modules is not supported.
  require() of /Users/hasan/apps/zaghop/v2/API/node_modules/serverless-offline/src/index.js from /usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
  Instead rename index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from /Users/hasan/apps/zaghop/v2/API/node_modules/serverless-offline/package.json.
  
      at new NodeError (internal/errors.js:322:7)
      at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1102:13)
      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    ....
```

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    "target": "es6",                                /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                           /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],                                   /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    "allowJs": true,                             /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    "removeComments": true,                      /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                                 /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "noImplicitAny": false,                       /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",                  /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    "baseUrl": ".",                             /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    "paths": {                                   /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
        "@src/*": ["src/*"]
    },                                 
    "esModuleInterop": true,                        /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    /* Experimental Options */
    "experimentalDecorators": true,              /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,               /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */

    /* Advanced Options */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                           /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true        /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "coverage"],
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

My current Node version:

```
➜  node -v
v14.18.2
```

Tried changing it to 12 like below

```
➜  nvm use 12
Now using node v12.22.8 (npm v6.14.15)
```

That didn't help

Any suggestions?

Comment: checkout this [github issue](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/9283), they suggest using `"type": "module" in package.json` and adding `serverless-plugin-typescript` plugin

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly, thanks for helping. I tried that earlier but didn't fix the issue. My repo is here: https://github.com/hasanfar/serveless-node-ts
Please take a look if you have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also facing the same issue. I solved it by installing v3 of `serverless`.  As, the v9 of `serverless-offline` supports only v3 of Serverless, it worked after I updated my `serverless` to latest version.

Comment: Thanks, Harsh. I tried upgrading to v3 using the command: 
npm install -g serverless   

When I looked up the version using sls --version, it shows Framework Version:         2.4.0 instead of 3.x. I even tried installing by npm install -g serverless@3 but the same result. Any thoughts?
==================

Operating System:          darwin

     Node Version:              14.18.2

     Framework Version:         2.4.0

     Plugin Version:            4.6.0

     SDK Version:               n/a

     Components Version:        3.9.2

Comment: Thanks, Harsh. It works now. I had to manually remove the older version

Comment: Also just curious to know the source where you got the clue about Serverless-offline v8 compatibility. Mind sharing that?

Comment: @Hasteq So. I faced a similar issue couple of months back with node-fetch package. Basically they have released a breaking change with v3. So I assumed it's same with serverless-offline and when I checked it's release history in it's repo, they have clearly mentioned that for v9 they are now supporting only v3 of Serverless. 
https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline/releases/tag/v9.0.0

Comment: Thanks, Harsh, for sharing the insight

Comment: I'm having the same issue with serverless version 3.27 and serverless offline v12.0. I'll try using a different library to node-fetch